# Is it still possible for a MDM server to get the IMEI with iOS12?

Tags: mdm, ios12

After upgrading to iOS12 we noticed that the IMEI was apparently not transmitted to the MDM server anymore.
Is there a workaround?

Comment: Did you find a solution yet ?

Comment: No, do you have the same problem?

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for this issue? I have reported this as a bug to Apple.

Comment: hi i had noticed that IMEI still coming if sim card is present in the iOS 12 @JanMoritz